# Get only NON reply tweets from Spring Tweet API

Tags: java, spring, twitter, spring-social

I want to get tweets of my home timeline BUT NOT those tweets which I made as a reply (not retweet) on some other tweet. I crawled the whole Spring Twitter API but could not find a way to check if the Tweet object is a reply to another tweet or at least retrieve only tweets which are NOT a reply.

*Tweet Class has those boolean getter:*

```
 boolean    isFavorited() 

 boolean    isRetweet() 

 boolean    isRetweeted()
```

Now I do miss a `boolean isReply()`
Does anybody has an idea how to check this or retrieve non-reply tweets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Using spring-social you can use `tweet.getInReplyToUserId()` to check if the value is null, in that case, the tweet it's not a reply.

[HERE](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/Tweet.html) you have all the operations of the Class Tweet.

**OLD**: You can check the property `in_reply_to_screen_name` or `in_reply_to_status_id` for example. If they are null, the tweet it's not a reply.

[Here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) you can see all the properties.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - but Spring is an abstraction higher - actually I need to change it on that level. You know a way to explicitly access native Twitter API properties through Spring Twitter API?

Comment: Maybe you can try with `tweet.getInReplyToUserId()`. Looks like it will do the same. You can see all the operations [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/Tweet.html)

Comment: Ah okay - I just found that one, too please post it as answer!